# CoRoT FITS files read error

Tags: ds9, fits-header

I downloaded fits file using wget script from https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/docs/datasethelp/ETSS_CoRoT.html
I am not able to view the file. I tried atsromagic and DS9 .  After File->Open I get an error message "..error while reading.." .It happens with both softwares. 
Is anyone able to view these files? If yes, which software did you use?
Another possibility is that using using wget script on windows it got corrupted. Is there a command line tool to check integrity/validity of fits file?

Comment: Can you please specify which fits file you downloaded?

Comment: @samcarter AN2_STAR_0000000020_20070131T110634_20070402T071215.fits  wget -O AN2_STAR_0000000020_20070131T110634_20070402T071215.fits .  The script to download is http://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/data/ETSS/corot_astero/FITSfiles/IRa01/AN2_STAR_0000000020_20070131T110634_20070402T071215.fits -a corot_astero_IRa01_wget.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are FITS binary tables not FITS images so the normal FITS image tools very likely  won't read them. You have a couple of options to examine and manipulate them:

- Use the ['fv' tool](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftools/fv/) which works on FITS images or tables (and integrates with `ds9`)
- Use [TOPCAT](http://www.star.bris.ac.uk/~mbt/topcat/), a very powerful tool for examining, plotting and many other operations on all formats of tables (not just FITS ones)
- Use Python and [AstroPy Tables](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/index.html) e.g.

```
from astropy.table import Table

table = Table.read('EN2_STAR_CHR_0102990364_20070206T133547_20070401T235934.fits') 
table
<Table length=71042>
          DATE                DATEJD            DATEHEL       STATUS ...     BG    CORREC_RED CORREC_GREEN CORREC_BLUE
  yyyy-mm-jjThh:mi:ss    COROT JULIAN DAY   COROT JULIAN DAY         ... ELECTRONS ELECTRONS                          
        bytes23              float64            float64       int32  ...  float32   float32     float32      float32  
----------------------- ------------------ ------------------ ------ ... --------- ---------- ------------ -----------
2007-02-06T13:35:47.000   2593.06626508258 2593.0705519515977     16 ... 373.35654        0.0          0.0         0.0
2007-02-06T13:44:19.000  2593.072191038021 2593.0764776164892      0 ... 378.81073        0.0          0.0         0.0
```

Comment: 'fv' worked for me.

Comment: Mentioning so that it saves other people time. I attempted to install TOPCAT. It needed JRE.  But the download site of JRE seems to require an ORACLE id. I gave up at that point.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be something Oracle have changed recently. The [Open JDK](https://jdk.java.net/13/) should work just as well (and doesn't require signing up)